# Facebook API batch request is very slow

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a web app that allows users to search data from their Facebook profile as well as that of their friends (who've also authorized the app). Initially I was looping through the friends and making separate API calls to get the friend data, but that was SUPER slow. So I switched to building an array of API requests and submitting one [batch request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).

The batch request is supposed to be the solution to my problem, but it's STILL agonizingly slow. My page loads are around 15 seconds and I cannot figure out why. The documentation claims that each request in the batch is processed in parallel, but it sure doesn't seem that way. Is it relevant that each of my batched requests takes an unique access token? The documentation doesn't indicate that this is a problem, but the documentation doesn't say a lot of things...

Here's an example of one of my batch queries:

```
[
{"method":"GET",
"relative_url":"\/#####\/friends?fields=name,first_name,last_name,id,work,education&access_token=#####"},
{"method":"GET",
"relative_url":"\/#####\/friends?fields=name,first_name,last_name,id,work,education&access_token=#####"},
{"method":"GET",
"relative_url":"\/#####\/friends?fields=name,first_name,last_name,id,work,education&access_token=#####"}
]
```

Just to give you some context, the app makes one API request to get the user's friends. Then it loops through those results and builds a batch request for each friend (that has authorized the app) and sends a second API batch request using the PHP SDK ($json_batch is a batch request like the one shown above):

```
$rawdata = $facebook->api('?batch='.$json_batch, 'POST');
```

(exemplified above). The cumulative results are checked for matches against the user's search query and echoed back to the user.  Any ideas why this should take 20 seconds to happen??

**UPDATE:** 
I added some code to track the time at various times during the execution of the script...
The entire class runs in 11-13 seconds. The first FB api call (to the graph) takes 0.6 seconds. The second batch call is 10-11 seconds! But WHY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the batch requests take that long, but to answer the access token per request, no it's necessarily to do so, unless you put different tokens, if you are using the same token then you can simply (as in the documentation):

```
curl \
    -F 'access_token=…' \
    -F 'batch=[ \
            {"method": "GET", "relative_url": "me"}, \
            {"method": "GET", "relative_url": "me/friends?limit=50"} \
        ]'\
    https://graph.facebook.com
```

You can however get the same exact information using a [single FQL query](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20uid,%20username,%20name,%20first_name,%20middle_name,%20last_name,%20work,%20education%20FROM%20%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29):

```
SELECT uid, username, name, first_name, middle_name, last_name, work, education 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

This also removes the need to query separably for the friends of the logged in user first, but if you do have a list of friend ids you can put those in the `IN` clause instead of the inner query.
Maybe this fql solution will return faster.

Comment: Thanks Nitzan. I was worried that the answer might turn out to be FQL... I've been avoiding it up until now, but maybe it's time to "bite the bullet" and re-write the API call as FQL. I'll try to do some tests and report back.

Comment: Why have you been avoiding fql?

Comment: I'm not very proficient with MySQL, so it's less intuitive for me to learn. Is it easy to translate one of my batched queries above? I'd like to try a batched fql query asap just see if there's a significant speed difference... then get invest the time to learn it better.

Comment: Have you used the query I posted in my answer? It should give all of the fields you asked for in your batch requests, and give you the results for all of the friends of the logged in user... Just click the `single FQL query` link in my answer and see the results in the explorer tool.

Comment: That's great, but I'm not sure how to actually include it in the batch call. For example, should I be building a JSON object with requests like this: `'relative_url' : '/fql?q={SELECT+name,+first_name,+last_name,+id,+work,+education+FROM+friends}&access_token='.$token`

I don't quite get the mechanics of how to convert what I'm doing into FQL

Comment: No, you don't need a batch request at all. You make one http request with that query. There's a php example in the [FQL documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

Comment: I see. It will take me some time because I will have to re-write a lot of my code. I'll give it a try and report back.

For what it's worth, I just tested it using a batched query with your FQL query and it's just as slow. So I'm hoping the batch query is the problem.

Comment: Fine, take your time, but just know that you can just try things using curl.

Comment: I've seen that notation all over the documentation, but I confess I don't really get how to use it. Is it the command line?

Comment: Or do I use it with: `file_get_contents()`? I feel dumb for asking, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) is `command line tool for getting or sending files using URL syntax`, there's an extension for php so that it can be used from a script. If you have it installed then you use it as the documentation in facebook show.

Comment: I've been trying to run it from the OSX terminal but nothing happens. Should I be able to copy/paste those examples? Or do I have to pipe out the results or do something else to see the return value?

Comment: Wait wait wait... I just realized that there's a problem with this approach. How can I get the friends' `work` field without using that user's access token?

Comment: You can ask for the `friends_work_history` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from the logged in user.

Comment: Right. But that doesn't let me get `friends_work_history` from the **friends of the friends** of the logged in user. Remember, some of the logged in user's friends have also authorized the app, so it needs to search them as well. This was the reason for the batched query in the first place.

Comment: There's no way to get the data of the friends of friends. If you want that then you'll need to use a different token, one of a friends which has the app installed as well.

Comment: Exactly! That's what I was doing with the batch request. Each of the requests used a different access token. It worked fine but it was very slow. Is there a way to do this with FQL?

Comment: Oh, I see, that wasn't obvious from the start..  Well then, even with FQL you'll need to do a batch request or make a few different requests. But you can't have the user wait for the result, it will take too long.

Comment: So do you think it's worth it to convert my batch request into a batch of FQL requests? Apparently this is allowed, but I don't know if this will be any faster than what I'm already doing. Do you?

Comment: I think you'll need to run some tests, but I'm pretty sure that in your scenario you won't be able to get to a good enough time. It sounds like a job to run in the background and not something a user needs to wait for.